# Trying to create a gird using a 2D Array and nested loop but get undefined as a result within the array

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, undefined, nested-loops

```js
function makeGrid(numColumns, numRows) {
  var grid = [];
  var rows = [];

  var columns = [];
  for(let i = 0; i < numRows; i++) { 
     grid[i] = [];
     for(let j = 0; j < numColumns; j++) {
       grid[i][j] = columns[j];
     }
  }
  return grid;
}

console.log(makeGrid(3,4));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important;top: 0;}
.as-console-row::after {display: none !important;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You were on the right track! Just like you had to create an array for each row, you have to also create an array for each column:

```js
function makeGrid(numColumns, numRows){
  const grid = [];
  for(let i = 0; i < numRows; i++){
     grid[i] = [];
     for(let j = 0; j < numColumns; j++){
       grid[i][j] = []; // Previously: columns[j]
     }
  }
  return grid;
}

console.log(makeGrid(3,4));
```

On closer inspection after this fix, your variables `rows` and `columns` were unused. I removed them.

Also, you should prefer [`let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) and [`const`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const) over [`var`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var), where applicable. In short: `let` and `const` are more similar to how variable declarations and scoping work in other languages, and unlike `var` they don't come with the (potentially confusing) features of being hoisted and redeclarable.

Comment: thanks for your help you helped me achieve the answer i was looking for, and I have taken on borad using let and const from now on

Answer (score 0):

```js
function makeGrid(numColumns, numRows){
    var grid = []
    
    for(let i = 0; i < numRows; i++){
        grid.push([])
        for(let j = 0; j < numColumns; j++){
            `turns out I was meant to make the grid equal to "j+1"`
            grid[i][j] = j+1;
        }
    }
    return grid
}
    
console.log(
    makeGrid(3,4)
)
```